# Pass values between pages

Tags: php

I have a page called `connect.php`

This page connects with twitter and gets the values using OAuth. So this page contains values like this:

```
$id = 1;
$provider = 'twitter';
$name = 'Tom';
```

Now I have another page called `email.php`

This page has a form where a user can enter his email address. Now I would like to pass the values from `connect.php` to `email.php`.

Once the email is entered by the user, I would like to insert that data into my database. Can someone point me in the right direction by giving some resources?

Comment: First result on google when searching your question :\ [here](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php)

Comment: @AlexLunix Yes I've seen that page already. That page only dealing with form fields. From form page to another page. But my question is exact opposite.

Comment: Read [this part](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php#session).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use PHP sessions - http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php.

For your needs you could do something like this.

In connect.php:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = 1;
$_SESSION['provider'] = 'twitter';
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Tom';
```

In email.php:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['id']; // echoes 1

    // do something
}

if(isset($_SESSION['provider']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['provider']; // echoes twitter

    // do something
}

if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['name']; // echoes name

    // do something
}
```